# Does the kbd element help at all in terms of accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm writing a blog post about the `kbd` element, and as part of that I'm trying to see if it actually helps in terms of accessibility, e.g. do any screen readers reckognise the `kbd` element or do anything with it?

I've tried googling around for an answer but turned up nothing (possibly attributed to how few people actually use this element?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not seem to be any evidence of any particular handling of the `kbd` element in browsers, assistive software, or otherwise, except for the default rendering (which uses the browser’s default monospace).

It is difficult to image what any software *could* do with it, since it simply indicates that some text is presented as user input – it just represents it, without actually involving any user interaction. And the content can be just about anything. User input is often a command or a filename or other “computerish” expression, but it could equally well be in a natural language or a meaningless string (say, a password).

Comment: Jukka is correct. I just ran a quick test, and the accessibility tree in Firefox doesn't really expose any information about <kbd> elements. The only difference is that it gets broken up into separate "text leaf"s—but the same is true if you use <span>s (thus there's no semantic info available to the SR). Also confirmed that NVDA & JAWS don't read it any differently with or without <kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense if screen readers read the content marked up with `kbd` in a different tone/voice/speed/etc. (resp. announce it).

Otherwise it would not be (always/perfectly) clear what should be entered and what not.

Example where it would not be clear what exactly to type in:

```
<p><kbd>Say hi</kbd> to get an introduction.</p>
<!-- vs. -->
<p>Say <kbd>hi</kbd> to get an introduction.</p>
```

Example where it would not be clear that anything should be typed in at all:

```
<p>
  <kbd>kill</kbd> to kill yourself, <kbd>kill <var>name</var></kbd> to kill the player named <var>name</var>
</p>
```

Example where it would not be clear if/which punctuation has to be entered and if keys have to be hold (`+`):

```
<p>To enable god mode, press <kbd>a+v!c</kbd>.</p>
<!-- vs. -->
<p>To enable god mode, press <kbd>a+v!c.</kbd></p>
<!-- vs. -->
<p>To enable god mode, press <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>v!c</kbd>.</p>
```

If *any* screen readers ship with `kbd` support enabled by default is another question, that probably can't be answered for sure, because there are *many* screen readers that are available only for one language resp. in one country (let alone all the different versions).

But I guess most advanced screen readers can be configured to "do anything" with `kbd`. I know that many screen reader users share snippets/configs on mailing lists to improve their experiences. I wouldn't be surprised if some also added some support for `kbd`.

Besides from accessibility for screen reader users, `kbd` can help other users, too, of course. I've often looked at the source to figure out what exactly should be entered when `kbd` didn't get any special styling.